# Can Bluetooth earphone leak data between phones?

Tags: privacy, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth earphone connects to both iPhone and android. I forgot to switch off the connection of android when using iPhone. So I am wondering if the sound of iPhone or even the iPhone data privacy could be recorded or leaked to that andriod  phone when they were both connected to the same Bluetooth earphone. Or this is just a wild speculation?

If your android is hacked, can the  hacker record and see what you do in real-time on the iPhone because of this shared Bluetooth device situation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes the earphones are a slave device and the phones are master devices. Each Bluetooth pairing is distinct using a different Longterm Key negotiated at the point of 1st pairing and then re-used as part of session authentication. There is no reason why a Bluetooth device should 'leak' information to another paired device.

Regards the 2nd part of your question, if your android is hacked, there is no immediate reason why an attacker could take advantage of a Bluetooth pairing to the ends you describe. Even if the attacker rooted your android they'd still have a job to use your iphone in this way. Apple phone security is pretty good. Everything is sandboxed. So they'd have to get you to grant permissions to the Bluetooth device they're masquerading as to use things like the camera and the microphone. It would be more straightforward to hack your iphone than to hack an Android to then hack an iPhone.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! So that means it should be ok if keep my Bluetooth connected to both phones simultaneously without being worrying too much right? Or you still recommend I should always decouple one from another just for the peace of my mind?

Comment: I'd say safety is a concern for you and so, for peace of mind, disconnect. Also, it saves battery life so that's a plus.